# Issue with spacing nodes in networkx graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, graph-visualization

I'm trying to make a networkx graph with several hundred edges:

```
def generate_network_graph(graph):
    visual_graph = networkx.Graph()
    for edge in graph.edges:
        visual_graph.add_edge(edge.actor.name, edge.movie.title)
    plt.figure(3, figsize=(30, 30))
    networkx.spring_layout(visual_graph, k=0.9, iterations=20)
    networkx.draw_spring(visual_graph)
    plt.show()
```

No matter how much I seem to increase k, however, my graph comes out looking like a clustered mess:

[image]

I'm not sure what else to do keep the nodes from overlapping; I've tried a range of k values from 0.0 to 5.0. I thought about decreasing the size of the nodes, but I'm not sure if that would just make the graph less readable. Not only that, but regenerating this graph takes an abysmal amount of time, ~15 minutes. Am I simply not using the right graph library for the job? Or is there something I can modify to make my graph clearer.

Comment: 1. You are not actually using the layout that you are pre-computing. Hence any changes to `k` are not propagated, and then `draw` uses the default `k=1.`. 2. One thing that would probably improve the quality immediately is if you only drew the largest connected component. In this way you won't have some stray bit floating around that strongly affect your axes and reduce the space available for the majority of the graph.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### From the documentation

`k : float (default=None)
    Optimal distance between nodes.  If None the distance is set to
    1/sqrt(n) where n is the number of nodes.  Increase this value
    to move nodes farther apart.`

You can try the following:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Set an exemple graph
edge_list = [(1,2),(2,0),(2,4),(3,4)]
g = nx.Graph(edge_list)

# plot
pos = nx.spring_layout(g, k=0.3*1/np.sqrt(len(g.nodes())), iterations=20)
plt.figure(3, figsize=(30, 30))
nx.draw(g, pos=pos)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(g, pos=pos)
plt.show()
```

Here `k`is proportional to `1/np.sqrt(len(g.nodes()))`, thus nodes are still well separated even when the number of nodes increases.